# Accessing Protected members by inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

In this piece of code I am trying to access the protected members of the base class from the derived class . But in the derived class it says that "Cannot access protected member"

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:

    Employee(char Name, int perHrPay) { Name_user=Name, PerHr=perHrPay;};
    Employee() {}
    ~Employee() {}
    char getName() const;
    float getPayPerHr() const;
    float paymentIs() const ;

protected:
    char Name_user;
    float PerHr; 
};

class Manager : public Employee
{
public:
    Manager(){}
    ~Manager(){}
    float paymentIs() const ;
};

char Employee::getName() const { return Name_user; }
float Employee::getPayPerHr() const { return PerHr; }
float Employee::paymentIs() const { return PerHr*3; }


int main()
{
    Employee emp('S',94);
    Manager man;
    cout << " The name is " << emp.getName() << endl;
    cout << "The per hr pay is " << emp.getPayPerHr() << endl;
    cout << "The payment is " << emp.paymentIs() << endl;    
    cout << "Name inherited" << man.Name_user << endl;
    cout << "Per hr pay is " << man.PerHr << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

In this code man is not able to access protected member Name_user in the class Employee. I am not understanding why the inherited class not able to access it.
Please help

Comment: Make Employee's destructor `virtual`, as well as `float paymentIs()`

Comment: Protected members are not accessible from an outer scope. Just like private.

Comment: `main()` should return 0 upon successful termination. You can just leave it out for C++11 (and onward).

Answer (score 4):

Inherited class is able to access protected members, but in your code you are trying to access it from `main` function , not from derived class methods...

Comment: In short: Add accessor methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to access `Name_user` or `PerHr` from either `emp` or `man` in `main()`.

The implementation of `Manager` is permitted to access protected members ofr `Employee`. And users or `Manager` are permitted to use the public interfaces of `Employee`, since it publicly inherits from `Employee`.

So, from `man`, use the accessor methods just as you did for `emp`.

```
    cout << "Name inherited" << man.getName() << endl;
    cout << "Per hr pay is " << man.getPayPerHr() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

> In this code `man` is not able to access protected member `Name_user` in the class `Employee`

You need to get clarity on what "X accesses Y" means in C++ terms.

Above, `X` must be a *function*; data members and local variables cannot "access" anything, because they are passive.

In your example, it is incorrect to say that `man` "accesses" anything in `man.Name_user`, because `man` is not a function.

The function in this case is `main`, and it tries to access `Name_user` in the `Manager` class. It is a protected member, so free-standing functions such as `main` cannot access it.

In order to get around this, make a public member function in `Manager`, and access `Name_user` from it:

```
class Manager : public Employee
{
public:
    Manager(){}
    ~Manager(){}
    float paymentIs() const ;
    char name_user() const { return Name_user; }
};
```

Now `main` can gain read access to `Name_user` by calling `man.name_user()` function.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` means that the member can be accessed from a function belonging to the derived class, like `Manager::paymentIs` (with some other restrictions).

In your code, the expressions attempting to use members `Name_user` and `PerHr` are in function `main`, which has no rights to any private or protected members of `Employee` or `Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from inside the derived class but not from `main` (or from anywhere else except `Employee` and it's derived class).

In a method inside `Manager`, you will be able to access `protected` members of `Employee`, but will not be able to access `private` members of `Employee`. Outside of `Employee` and `Manager` (like in `main`), you can access only `public` members.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Name inherited" << man.Name_user << endl;
cout << "Per hr pay is " << man.PerHr << endl;
```

You can't access protected members in main , You can only do this if they are public .